# Repository Pattern With asynchronous

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, repository

I wrote this code in my Repository

```
Task<bool> UpdateUserAsync(User user);
```

But I do not know how to write supplementary code in the implementer class
This code receives the information of a user and edits it in the database
Given that this method must be Async

Comment: How do you access your database ? Do you use an ORM (Entity Framework), ADO.NET, a micro ORM (e.g. Dapper) etc.

Comment: I access the database via EF core

Comment: I'd do some reading: [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application (9 of 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) , [The Repository Pattern is Dead If You Use Entity Framework](https://dotnetcultist.com/repository-pattern-dead-with-entity-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, post your code and you might get a better response but if you're asking about how to write an async method then it's pretty straightforward and clean.

If your "Repository" that you refer to is an interface and you're asking how to write your implementation async then you'll want to do something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateUserAsync(User user){
  // Check the user exists
  var existingUser = await GetUserAsync(user.Id);

  if (existingUser == null) {
    return false;
  }

  var success = await DoMySaveTransactions(); // This would be where you commit to your chosen backend.
  return success;
}
```

If you're asking about how to use your new repository then you'd use something like the following inside a method which is decorated with async.

```
async void UpdateUsername(User existingUser, string newUsername) {
  existingUser.username = newUsername;
  var success = await _myRepository.UpdateUserAsync(existingUser);

  // Do something with success.
}
```

If you want to use the implementation in a non async method then your code would be something like...

```
void UpdateUsername(User existingUser, string newUsername) {
  existingUser.username = newUsername;
  var success = myRepository.UpdateUserAsync(existingUser).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  // Do something with success.
}
```

If I've misunderstood what you're looking to do, please add some more explanation.

Comment: thank you
I want to write exactly this code for the Userpanel section
Inside the userpanel section there are a number of textboxes including email and password and username
That the user can change them
I want to get this user in my Controller and save this changed information in my database
It should be noted that I use asp.net core technology

Comment: You'll need a model then @ali and you'll need to post it to the controller method. The model needs the properties from the front and then you'll need to update your user model to reflect those changes uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem in the async part, or in the "fetch and update user" part?

The parts about "Fetch and update user" are difficult to describe if you don't tell us the method you are using to access the database: are you using entity framework? SQL?

### SQL, DbConnection, DbCommand

Let's assume you have already synchronous methods:

```
public User FetchUserById(int userId) {...}
private void UpdateExistingUser(User user) {...}
```

You will have to create similar async methods:

```
public Task<User> FetchUserByIdAsync(int userId);
private Task UpdateExistingUserAsync(User user);
```

If you use SQL, you will probably use class `DbCommand` and methods `ExecuteReader`, and `ExecuteNonQuery`. For your async methods, use similar async methods.

Note: to use DisposeAsync, you need C# 8. Otherwise use try ... finally and call DisposeAsync explicitly

```
private async dbConnection CreateFetchUserCommand(
    DbConnection Connection,
    int userId)
{
    var dbCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    dbCommand.CommandText = ...
    var dbParameter = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
    ... // etc.
    return dbCommand;
}

private async DbCommand CreateUpdateUserCommand(DbConnection connection, User user)
{
    var dbCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    dbCommand.CommandText = ...
    var dbParameter = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
    ... // etc.
    return dbCommand;
}

public Task<User> FetchUserByIdAsync(int userId)
{
    using (var dbConnection = new DbConnection(...))
    {
        await dbConnection.OpenAsync();
        using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateFetchUserCommand(dbConnection, userId))
        {
            using (var dataReader = await dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                 // use async methods to access fetched data
                 User user = await ...
                 return user;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly: add an UpdateExistingUserAsync which is similar to your existing UpdateUser.

```
public UpdateUser(User user)
{
    // TODO: exception if user null

    User existingUser = await FetchUserById(user.Id);
    if (existingUser == null)
    {
        // user does not exist
    }
    else
    {
        ... // copy values from user to existingUser
        await UpdateExistingUserAsync(existingUser); 
    }
}
```

The copying from user to existingUser makes it possible to update only the values that you provided. if you always want to update the complete user, then the FetchUserById is not necessary.

### Entity Framework

```
using (var dbConext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    User existingUser = await dbConnection.Users.FindAsync(user.Id)
    if (existingUser != null)
    {
        ... // copy values from user to existingUser
        await dbContext.SaveAsync();
}
```